# Enabling the log app on the WDTV

Tags: usb, network-adapter, logging, firmware, wdtv

Just flashed the last WDXLTV firmware on my WDTV and it's working fine.
I tried to config a Wifi USB adapter but couldn't get it to work.
Dropped the log-saver.app.bin on the root of the stick but didn't find any log files after booting.

What I'm doing is turning on the WDTV with the stick inserted (the stick is formatted with FAT32). Tried with the wireless-mod.app.bin required files and without any other file than the log saver.
I can't get a log file anyway.

All I want right now is to get the log file so I can debug the WI FI adapter.

Answer (score 1):

log-saver.app.bin works only on WDTV generation 1 models.

Comment: Mine is Generation 1. I finally got it to work, I didn't knew I had to unplug the device.
Thanks anyway!